# twitter4J PropertyConfiguration in 4.0.6

Tags: twitter4j

When changing to Twitter4J 4.0.6 my code, that I inherited, uses PropertyConfiguration static fields.  pre 4.0.6 the static fields were public.  so twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfiguration.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY was a valid thing to do.  in 4.0.6 these fields are now private.  So my [inherited] code no longer compiles.

what is the protocol now for getting the values of these fields in 4.0.6?

I have researched this and found nothing on the change.  I did find a lot of examples for pre 4.0.6 where the static fields were used just like my code does.  Is there documentation, or are there examples, for these fields in twitter4j 4.0.6?